# Individual file paths to CSV (AppleScript or JS)?

Tags: javascript, csv, automation, path, applescript

I'm trying to find a simpler solution than manually entering values into a spreadsheet. Essentially every file in a folder must show it's file path folders in columns per row, no matter how many folders deep (e.g., folder1\subfolder2\subfolder3\file.extension) So it's not uncommon to have to add columns to an existing spreadsheet (the spreadsheet has up to "Subfolder 3" so I'll have to add a column for every subfolder beyond that), but it is extremely time consuming for larger projects. Either I'm not searching the right parameters on this site, or I'm just brain fried from looking. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The requirement is not very clear. Perhaps restructure it to what are needed, what's the input, expected output, and give examples.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague. Essentially I'm trying to get a file and it's containing folder structure output as a CSV. So for example, say the file's directory is as such:

Folder1\Folder2\Folder2\Filename.ext

What I'm trying to output is a CSV where each folder and the file itself can be put into a spreadsheet, and each folder/subfolder is in its own column, So the output would be:

[Column A]Folder 1 [Column B]Folder2 {Column C]Folder3 [Column 4]Filename.ext

The only catch is that the amount of Folders-to-columns will change with each file. Thanks for the help!